# firebase bool passes to null bug

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Hello I am trying to change the data in firebase when I click the button from true to false and from false to true but when I click the value in the database goes to null.
Anyone know what’s wrong? Thank you.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool selected;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setInitialValue();
  }
  setInitialValue() async {
    final value = await _incrementCounter();
    setState(() {
      selected = value?? true;
    });
  }
  _loadCounter(bool value) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setBool('select', value);
  }
  Future<bool> _incrementCounter() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    bool boolValue = prefs.getBool('select');
    return boolValue;
  }
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Center(child: Text('ola'))),
            MaterialButton(
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              child: Text( 'Add', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white), ),
              onPressed: () {
                Firestore.instance.collection('teste').document('eHJzjbq6c7MwrObrR9XY').updateData({'mover' : selected});
                }
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the value of the `selected` variable is not being set correctly, hence when you try to update the document you're sending a null value. Try to verify the value of `selected` to check if it has indeed a boolean value before writing it to firestore.